# Json key format change in laravel

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-api

I created API like this Json response.

```
{
    "product_category_id": 1,
    "branch_id": 1,
    "product_category_code": "00184050",
    "product_Category_name": "books",
    "product_Category_imageURL": "books2.png",
    "product_Category_is_active": 1,
    "product_Category_created_at": "2023-02-25T10:55:48.000Z",
    "product_Category_updated_at": "2023-02-27T14:38:43.000Z",
    "product_Category__created_date": "2023-02-24T18:30:00.000Z",
    "product_Category_Created_by": 1,
    "product_Category_updated_by": 2
}
```

I need API like this.

```
{
    "productCategoryID": 1,
    "branchID": 1,
    "productCategoryCode": "00184050",
    "productCategoryName": "books",
    "productCategoryImageURL": "books2.png",
    "productCategoryIsActive": 1,
    "productCategoryCreatedAt": "2023-02-25T10:55:48.000Z",
    "productCategoryUpdatedAt": "2023-02-27T14:38:43.000Z",
    "productCategoryCreatedDate": "2023-02-24T18:30:00.000Z",
    "productCategoryCreatedBy": 1,
    "productCategoryUpdatedBy": 2
}
```

How To change this to entire application
Have any package to method

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use laraval helper classes.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
 
$converted = Str::camel('foo_bar');
 
// fooBar
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-camel-case

Comment: I need to make entire application

Comment: You can override the response class in the AppServiceProvider with the alias class and add str camel in the method that is used in the entire project.